# How to deal with distractions during meditation?

Tags: meditation

When meditating on the breath, after a while the sensation of my eyes not being closed properly appeared. This then turns into vibrating, and my eyes feel like they are literally moving. I tried refocusing on the breath but this is a very difficult sensation to ignore. Does anyone have advice?

Other sensations I feel are the opening of my eyes, if I do not pay attention to them. This sometimes happens, but mostly doesn't. This is also extremely distracting, as I feel like I should focus on keeping my eyes closed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Interesting question; if could mention approximate time amount before noticing eye adjustments, total approximate time for contemplation, contemplation method intended, position, position of hands & feet, posture, and environment, that could all be helpful for replying

Comment: @MH it's usually around 5 minutes before it starts, it's hard to tell. It is actually happening instantly at the current moment of time. Same amount of time for contemplation, and I only do breath meditation. I was sitting back straight, knees crossed and looking straight forward. Feet were under my knees, touching the floor, and my hands were on my lap facing up, hand in hand. The environment was on my bed looking out of a window, I like the fresh breeze I get whilst doing this. Although it still happens whilst in a chair or on the floor. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @MH did you delete your comment or am I imagining things?

Comment: @MH I see. I have noticed a further distraction whilst meditation, which is hard to deal with without focusing on it. Occasionally I will see a small light, but then realise my eyes are starting to open. Is this a distraction or my own fault?

Comment: Do I just ignore the opening and the light that appears from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Close the eyes properly?

Usually there appear various sensations like ie;

- posture not being straight
- legs not being very comfortable
- odd sensations in the face or body
- itching, numbing etc
- wanting to adjust posture etc

Usually when some odd sensation appears, it distracts you from the breath but if you were to switch your focus to the sensation the perception of breath would distract you from the sensation.

So there is not that much you can do as you will get distracted either way, so i try to do as little as possible.

Eventually the distracting sensations will change & subside, so you can just observe that arising, persisting and cessation in that.

What i do is aknowledging that ie 'a painful bodily feeling has arisen' and just observe it distracting me whilst maintaining focus on the breath and whatever else is going on.

When distracted just acknowledge that a distracting feeling, thought or perception (however it appears to you) has arisen and go back to breath. Keep observing the arising, persistence and cessation of both perceptions (breath + distraction) whilst reapplying the focus and keeping it connected to breathing.

One can't really do anything about various thoughts, feelings & perceptions claiming focus so one just aknowledges their arising, persistence and the cessation.

I don't necessarily take note as in verbalizing thoughts as is taught by ie Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu but i do it occasionally. I don't think it's a mistake to do it but i think it is eventually somewhat distracting and is not something you do in the 2nd jhana but it's ok up until that point if one finds it useful to keep focused.

I tend to be less "hands on" in general and tend to stay mindful of the arising, persisting & cessation of thoughts feelings & perceptions by applying mind to something and keeping it applied without intentionally giving rise to thoughts.

If i notice particular hindrances then i drop the perception of breathing to counter the hindrance lest it can be well countered by the perception of breath (ie general restlessness).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! How does one observe distraction whilst also focusing on the breath? I thought they meant the same-ish thing. Also could you expand on your last paragraph? I am interested.

Comment: If one gets sleepy doing breath meditation then it's almost impossible to wake oneself up. It's possible to sit through it and drift whilst nodding or napping until it passes or one falls asleep but the general sutta instruction is to wake oneself up otherwise, by first attending to a different theme, reciting texts, rubbing limbs, getting up etc see capala sutta for details.

Comment: When distracted just acknowledge that a distracting feeling, thought or perception (however it appears to you) has arisen and go back to breath. Keep observing the arising, persistence and cessation of both perceptions (breath + distraction) whilst reapplying the focus and keeping it connected to breathing. In last paragraph i meant that if you notice ie anger, sleepiness or lust you might want to switch to a different meditation object to develop perception of metta, arouse energy or develop perception of unattractiveness before returning to breath when anger, lust or drowsiness has subsided.

Comment: I understand. I usually do not notice any anger etc. so for now I will use the breath. By metta are you talking about loving-kindness meditation?

Comment: Yes loving-kindness.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of being reactive to the sensation merely observe it. Generally it will arise then depart. Then return to your breath. There are a lot of various kriyas that occur with meditation. Often it is different for everyone as energy channels are cleared. Once you start either being attracted to or adverse to the sensations, they persist until you let go. In general they are benign.
If they become intolerable, stop meditating and go get some exercise. Find a teacher who can look at your entire constitution and advise you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I assume the exercise is to tire the body out? I agree otherwise with the rest of your post, it's just a matter of practice for me. Also what are kriyas?

Comment: The exercise is to open energy channels so energy flows and eventually flows directly thru the central channel. 
Kriyas are movements such as jerking, shaking, semi involuntary muscle movements. Semi involuntary because they can be stopped and. The energy consciously guided back to the central channel. They are thought to be released of blocked energy. These are described in yoga Tantra, I am sure Buddhist tantric texts must address this as well. Kriyas comes from Sanskrit root kri = to do

Answer (score 1):

Bhante Vimalaramsi’s 6Rs seems to be a better way to deal with physical and mental distractions.
https://youtu.be/lY77In3ZYGI

Comment: Useful resource, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle these kind of distraction while occur when u start meditating.its a normal situation everyone of us experience when doing the 'anapana sati bawana' or the meditation on breathing.I suggest u to do some research or get some advice from a proper meditation teacher.There are many type of meditation methods in Buddhism not every method is work for everyone perfectly.Remember practice is the most important thing...only through continuous practice u can overcome those diverticulitis.Do more research on the type of meditation ur going to practice...seek help and advice from proper teachers...may u will overcome ur problem